# Connection problems on nginx proxied server (maybe a socket.io problem)

Tags: nginx, networking, socket.io, reverse-proxy

Hope somebody can help with this as I have struggled with this project for over 2 weeks – it’s driving me nuts!!!

**The Project**
I have an open source media player running on a Raspberry pi. I am wanting to access it via an HTTPS connection, so I have a domain name pointed at my home router. Port forwarding pointing to a separate server running nginx. I have a very basic nginx config which seems bona fide and it is sending SSL requests to my media server.

**The Error**

When I navigate to my https address for the media server, I can load the page and I can see the UI for the media player - BUT it is covered by a "grey-out" screen and has a never ending spinning wheel. So it’s not fully loading.

When I go to the Google Developer Console in Chrome, I get these hints/symptoms…

The media server; under normal conditions is meant to be accessed via HTTP on a local network. There are a bunch of connections that look like this:

`http://192.168.1.7/socket.io/?EIO=3&tran ...`

However, on an HTTPS connections I get lots of “red” entries. Like this:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M_HFcoc
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

So on HTTPS my requests are going to 127.0.0.1; when they should be going to 192.168.1.7. This seems to be a websocket / socket.io problem.

**The Config**

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
access_log off;
    sendfile        on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    #start server1 section
    server {
      listen        80;
      listen   443 ssl;
       server_name my-domain.com;
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            }
    }
}
```

**My attempt to fix**

After doing some research, I’ve added the following. Inside the http block, but outside the location block…

```
upstream io_nodes {
  ip_hash;
  server 192.168.1.7;
}
```

Then added a new location block….

```
location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://io_nodes/socket.io/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

**Questions**

So my attempt to fix does nothing. My first question is why does my server when proxied on port 80 work, then fails when I try on SSL? Socket.io connections are fine on an HTTP connection.

Whilst I have done a bit of research on socket.io and nginx – I have not explicitly followed the official nginx instructions which you can find [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/). Have I missed steps? That resource describes “Add JavaScript code like the following to the file that is delivered to your client” – I can’t do that. I have no control over what the media server is dishing out.

Can anyone please help me go forward? THANKS!